# Linking multiple pie charts to a single legend in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I have 3 similar pie charts. They use same dimension but different groups so, their legends look the same. Instead of having 3 same looking legends, I'd like to bind only a single legend to those charts. I tried creating a legend separately and assign it to the charts, however, it didn't work. Is there actually a way to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly supported by dc.js, but it is very similar to a legend on a composite chart. I think if you were willing to do some hacking, you could override the `legendables` function on the chart you want to put the legend with, and have it accumulate the legendables from its sibling charts.

Take a look at `pieChart.legendables`:
https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/src/pie-chart.js#L419

And then `compositeChart.legendables`
https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/src/composite-chart.js#L363

for inspiration.

If this is too much hacking for you, please [file an issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new). It would certainly be nice to support!